# How to automatically load changes on client browsers instantly after deployment?

Tags: javascript

We have a website on which we deploy changes from time to time. The issue is changes are not shown automatically until client closes all tabs for our website and opens a new one. We already tried headers in the index.html, added some code on the serviceWorker, and nothing. We are using react and apollo. We read some people use versions but the names of our static files are changed every time we deploy because we use webpack chunk tags. Some of our clients can't see the changes and it's frustrating. Help!!!!

Comment: https://deanhume.com/displaying-a-new-version-available-progressive-web-app/

Comment: Try implementing a socket connection.

Comment: Append a datetime string or hash to the file names of files you want to reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a expiry time for your static files, like if you deploying your changing in every 2 weeks so give expiry date as 14 days.

After time expired browser automatically loads all files again. browser delete all static cached files after time expired and load new.

Comment: "Set a expiry time for your static files" can you explain how to do this?

Comment: refer this link  - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/caching/